# Javascript - how do i add cost?

Tags: javascript, html

How would i add a cost for the check boxes. When i add a onClick it said myFunction was not defined. I Don't know what i am doing. I was trying to make a check with the second function so if it was checked it would add the costs together and make a subtotal but i cant get it to work or find a way to get the costs to be a value in the check boxes

```
<html>
   <body>
      <p>A pizza is 13 dollars with no toppings.</p>
      <form action="form_action.asp">
         <input type="checkbox" name="pizza" value="Pepperoni" id="pep" > Pepperoni + 5$<br>
         <input type="checkbox" name="pizza" value="Cheese" id="ch" >Cheese + 4$<br>
         <br>
         <input type="button" onClick="myFunction()" value="Send order"><br>
         <input type="button" onClick="cost()" value="Get cost" > <br>
         <input type="text" id="order" size="50">
      </form>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         function myFunction() {
             var pizza = document.forms[0];
             var txt = "";
             var i;
             for (i = 0; i < pizza.length; i++) {
                 if (pizza[i].checked) {  // this shows the you ordered the pizza with blank topping 
                     txt = txt + pizza[i].value + " ";
                 }
             }
             document.getElementById("order").value = "You ordered a pizza with: " +    txt;
         }


         function cost() {
           var x = document.getElementById(pep).checked;  // this is the failed check and i dont know how to fix it and get it to add a cost
           document.getElementById("demo").innerhtml = x;
         }
      </script>
      <p id="demo"></p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try to define your function before form tag.

Answer (score 0):

answer that https://stackoverflow.com/users/7488236/manish-poduval got

```
<html>
<body>

<p>A pizza is 13 dollars with no toppings.</p>

<form action="form_action.asp">
<input type="checkbox" name="pizza" value="Pepperoni" id="pep">Pepperoni + 5$<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="pizza" value="Cheese" id="che">Cheese + 4$<br>
<br>
<input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Send order">
<input type="button" onclick="cost()" value="Get cost">
<br><br>
 <input type="text" id="order" size="50">
 </form>

<script>
function myFunction() {
var pizza = document.forms[0];
var txt = "";
var i;
for (i = 0; i < pizza.length; i++) {
    if (pizza[i].checked) {
        txt = txt + pizza[i].value + " ";
    }
}
document.getElementById("order").value = "You ordered a pizza with: " + txt;
}

function cost() {
var pep = 5;
var che = 4;
var pizza = 13;
var total = 0;
if (document.getElementById("pep").checked === true) {
  total += pep;
}

if (document.getElementById("che").checked === true) {
  total += che;
}
  document.getElementById("order").value = "The cost is : " + total;
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("pep").checked;
```

You have not written this line properly. after this check the value of x if it is true then add the value 5$ to 13$ and sum it up the cost and display it on a text field.

Let me know if it works or not.